# Put histogram side-by-side

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to group an histogram rowstacked in gnuplot similar to this image:

[image: Example of an histogram]

I have these 2 files where the data from the histogram comes from:

```
#Round-robin             
Input           West-Virginia   ChicagoI        ChicagoII       California
1500            28          25    28     19
3000            30          24    25     21
4500            28          28    25     19
6000            34          25    23     18
```

```
#Min-makespan                
Input                        West-Virginia ChicagoI      ChicagoII     California
1500                         34          20           30          17
3000                         33          30           21          16
4500                         31          23           38          9
6000                         42          21           38          0
```

```
plot for [i=2:5] 'cloudusage-roundrobin.dat' using i:xtic(1), \
     for [i=2:5] 'cloudusage-minmakespan.dat' using i:xtic(1)
```

1 - My plot instruction stack both histograms, instead of having them side-by-side. How I put them side-by-side, and also with the 2 xx labels ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `newhistogram` to start a new histogram. In order to use the same linetype, you must give the second call to `newhistogram` the option `lt 1`:

```
reset
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1
set bmargin 4
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid border lt -1
set key autotitle columnheader horizontal

plot newhistogram 'Cluster 1', \
     for [i=2:5] 'cloudusage-roundrobin.dat' using i:xtic(1),\
     newhistogram 'Cluster 2' lt 1, \
     for [i=2:5] 'cloudusage-minmakespan.dat' using i:xtic(1) notitle
```

Result with 4.6.4:

[image]