# Gnuplot: multi-layered xtics

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a bar graph, where I have three experimental groups and I measure certain values for each of them (two series of data for each group). However, the groups are further subdivided into subgroups and I would like to have that reflected in the values displayed on the `x`-axis.

The standard way to do this would be to define `xtics` to be equal to the full group descriptor, something like `Group 1, Subgroup 1`, `Group 1, Subgroup 2`, etc., but this does not look very nice. I have noticed that Excel would allow one to have two rows underneath the `x`-axis, as in the attached example.

**Is something similar possible in Gnuplot?**

[image: Example plot showing the idea]

Comment: You can use `plot newhistogram title 'Group 1', 'data.dat' ... ` for this

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22871516/2604213 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/23406222/2604213